# ORACLE - Selecting Parameters for calling Procedure from Table

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, parameter-passing

Is it possible to select the parameters for calling a procedure from the select statement?

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE_NAME(para1,para2,para3,para4);
commit;
```

Is it possible to select para1,para2,para3,para4 from a select query?

```
EXECUTE PROCEDURE_NAME((SELECT PARA1,PARA2,PARA3,PARA4 FROM TABLEA))
COMMIT;
```

I do not have access to modify the procedure.

Comment: One parameter at a time? ... probably.  What error message did you get when you tried it?

Comment: I don't think you can do it this way. But you can `SELECT PARA1, PARA2, PARA3, PARA4 INTO P1, P2, P3, P4 FROM TABLEA` and then `EXECUTE PROCEDURE_NAME(P1, P2, P3, P4)`

Comment: How many rows does that select return? Are you trying to pass  the values from all those rows to the procedure?

Comment: @KaushikNayak just 1 row.

Comment: It is good to use method in Alex's answer if there are few parameters like 3 or 4 as in your example. However, it is not advisable to create a procedure that takes so many arguments all coming from  columns of a single table / query. A ref cursor would be a better approach.

Answer (score 1):

As a slight variation on what @vc74 suggested, you could just replace your `EXECUTE` command (which, assuming this is SQL*Plus or SQL Developer anyway, is just a wrapper for an anonymous block anyway) with an explicit anonymous block:

```
begin
  for r in (SELECT PARA1,PARA2,PARA3,PARA4 FROM TABLEA) loop
    PROCEDURE_NAME(r.PARA1,r.PARA2,r.PARA3,r.PARA4);
  end loop;
end;
/
```

(I've left the bits from your original call uppercase and the new bits lower case mostly to distinguish them.)

Using a loop just means you don't need to declare local variables and select into those. It would also allow you to process multiple rows from the table, though I see form a comment you only expect one row. However, the flip side of that is it won't complain if there are no rows, or if there is more than one row, as the variable approach would do.

You could also use a record type to avoid declaring all the parameters separately:

```
declare
  l_row tablea%rowtype;
begin
  SELECT * into l_row FROM TABLEA;
  PROCEDURE_NAME(l_row.PARA1,l_row.PARA2,l_row.PARA3,l_row.PARA4);
end;
/
```

This now does expect exactly one row to be found in the table.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the functions in sql. So if you are able to create a function in your schema then you can do the following:

- create a function `function_name` in your schema that calls the procedure `procedure_name` and returns some dummy result
- use this function in sql query: `select function_name(para1,para2,para3,para4) from tablea`

example of function:

```
create or replace function function_name(
  p1 varchar2,
  p2 varchra2,
  p3 varchar2,
  p4 varchar2
) return number
is
begin
  procedure_name(p1,p2,p3,p4); -- here you execute the procedure
  return null;
end;
```

Comment: so I would pass 4 parameters to that function? and return 4 values? can you please share some example of the function

Comment: yes, the list of parameters in function is the same as in the base procedure

Comment: in the function does `execute procedure_name(para1,para2,para3,para4)` is the right syntex?

Comment: I've edited post - added an example of function. The incoming parameter types and order should be the same you have in procedure.